# Count events using Parse and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I use Unity and download Parse to use the ParseAnalytics to register events in my game.

Every time a player get a reward I set an event track using

ParseAnalytics.TrackEventAsync("Reward"+rewardsType);

I see the number of analytics requests(the request are working), but when I try to see the number of times a specific request was made using the 'Explorer' button on Parse, I see the eventName, installationID and other things, but I want to see how many times a player run the request, example:

EventName: RewardGOLD - 7 times

It's possible to do that in Parse using analytics?

Comment: Yes, if you go to the Analytics Dashboard, then click on 'Events' on the left, open the dropdown and select 'Custom Breakdown'. Then you can choose the event you want to filter for.

Comment: I find the 'Custom Breakdown' option, and it possible to see some events in there to choose, but the strange part is that not all events are available to choose